# Measure admitting any value

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a non-negative, Borel measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

- $\mu(A)=0$ for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|A|< \infty$
- $\infty >\mu \left( S(a,r) \right) >0$ for any circle $S(a,r)$ centered at $a\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and radius $r>0$.

Prove that $\mu$ admits any positive value.

Actually I have no idea how to proceed, one can easily show that the measure is infinite on any open set yet I doubt if it helps...

Comment: You need some finiteness assumption. As written now, $$\mu \colon A \mapsto \begin{cases} 0 &, A \text{ is countable} \\ \infty &, A\text{ is uncountable}\end{cases}$$ satisfies the conditions but not the conclusion.

Comment: sorry I had something elese in mind in second dot, fixed now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider the sets $$A(r,\varphi) = \{ r(\cos \vartheta, \sin \vartheta) : 0 \leqslant \vartheta < \varphi\}$$ for $r > 0$ and $0 \leqslant \varphi \leqslant 2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r > 0$ and $\varphi \in [0,2\pi]$, let

$$A(r,\varphi) = \{ r(\cos \vartheta, \sin \vartheta) : \vartheta \in [0,\varphi)\}.$$

$A(r,\varphi)$ is a Borel set contained in $S(0,r)$, so $\mu(A(r,\varphi)) < +\infty$. For a fixed $r > 0$, consider

$$f_r(\varphi) = \mu(A(r,\varphi)).$$

$f_r$ is a monotonic function, with $f_r(0) = 0$ and $f_r(2\pi) = \mu(S(0,r))$.

Show that $f_r$ is continuous. Then choose a sequence $(r_n)$ of distinct radii such that

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \mu(S(0,r_n)) = +\infty.$$

Assemble the parts to conclude that $\mu$ attains every value in $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: Very nice solution, actually it is enough to show that every value between 0 and $\mu(S(0,r))$ is attained which is not so different from continuity after all. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For a monotonic function on an interval, the two are equivalent. A monotonic function can have only jump discontinuities, and if it has one, it doesn't have the intermediate value property.